# Trying to make keyboard´s shortcut for Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, shortcut-keys

i'm trying to make a key shortcut for opening a terminal in a specific folder, how can i do it?
the default "terminal shortcut" uses the command "qterminal" but i need to open it in a specific folder. I appreciate your help

Comment: Welcome to AU. First things first comments aren't for adding info. You should [edit] the question to do that. Now, AFAIK, any Lubuntu 18.10 or newer uses `qterminal` and previous versions used `lxterminal`. As the name suggests, `gnome-terminal` is used for the Gnome DE, the standard Ubuntu, not Lubuntu.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for using comments, in stack-overflow i was told to use them for that kind of things. I tried changin "gnome-terminal" for "qterminal" because i know that lubuntu uses it, but it didn´t work too.